# CSS scoped to 1 div and all of its child elements

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to apply a CSS style to only a particular div and all of its children

```
<div id="1">lots of stuff i cant customize</div>
<div id="2">lots of other stuff I cant customize</div>
```

I want to apply styles1.css to div 1 and styles2.css to div 2.  Usually I would just use different class elements for each div and customize the CSS how I need it.  The problem is that I dont have access to the underlying code.  So I was hoping to have something like:

```
<div id="1" style="style1.css">lots of stuff i cant customize</div>
<div id="2" style="style2.css">lots of other stuff I cant customize</div>
```

I really dont care about the implementation if I have to use jquery or something, but I cannot modify the underlying divs/uls/etc... to modify their classes.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Just target it by id and it'll be the only thing affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to target them via their position in the parent's children.

```
div:nth-child(1) { /* apply style1 css here */ }
div:nth-child(2) { /* apply style2 css here */ }
```